# Implementing static shared counter in microservice architecture

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, azure-cosmosdb

I have a use case where i want to record data in rows and display to the user.
Multiple users can add these records and they have to be displayed in order of insertion AND - MOST IMPORTANTLY - with a sequence number starting from 1.

I have a Spring boot microservice architecture at the backend, which obviously means i cannot hold state in my boot application as i'm gonna have multiple running instances.

Another method was to fetch all existing records in the db,count them,increment the count by 1 and use that as my sequence. I need to do this every time i am doing an insert.

But the problem with the second approach is with parallel requests, which could result in same sequence number being given to 2 records.

Third approach is to configure the counter in a db , but since i am using cosmos DB, apparently that is also not an option.

Any suggestions as to how i can implement a static, shared counter ?

Comment: You can keep one counter in Redis( for faster read) . and when you need to increment it, then take a distributed lock on that counter field, increment the counter, update in Redis, release the lock and then save it in your Cosmos DB

Comment: You can think of publishing message by all services who updates the record to some jms Q ex: ```ActiveMQ```. and consume those messages and update the DB using specially designed service for counting.

Comment: For this use case, you can't keep counter as class static variable or for that matter it can't be anything that is tied to a JVM. What other options you have to store this counter ?  It has to be something outside your JVM. Now, irrespective of tech where you store your counter( Redis, RDBMS , FIle etc. ) , you would need a distributed lock in your system.